# How to store a file with Mongoose-Crate via an Express Route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, amazon-s3, mongoose

I am building a RESTful API using Node + Express 4 + MongoDB + Mongoose.

One thing my API needs to do is store and retrieve files. Which I will store in Amazon S3. Mongoose has a specific plugin for attaching files to Mongo documents called [Mongoose-Crate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-crate), which in turn has a storage provider [Mongoose-Crate-S3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-crate-s3) that uploads files to S3.

I've done my best to adapt the example code from the Mongoose-Crate-S3 npm page to work as an express route, but so far I've not gotten an image to successfully upload to my S3 storage. Documents of my 'file' model are being created in my mongo database, but the only have an '_id' and '__v' fields. No 'title', no 'description', nothing to indicate that the .post endpoint is actually receiving the files I try to post. I keep making slight adjustments to my code but I am generally getting some variation on "Could not get any response".

Here is my mongoose schema file.js (with my S4 credentials removed of course)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var crate = require('mongoose-crate');
var S3 = require('mongoose-crate-s3');

var FileSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String
});

FileSchema.plugin(crate, {
    storage: new S3({
        key: '<api-key-here>',
        secret: '<secret-here>',
        bucket: '<bucket-here>',
        acl: '<acl-here>', // defaults to public-read 
        region: '<region-here>', // defaults to us-standard 
        path: function(attachment) { // where the file is stored in the bucket - defaults to this function
            return '/' + path.basename(attachment.path)
        }
    }),
    fields: {
        file: {}
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('File', FileSchema);
```

And here is the relevant snippet of my api routes file. I'm fairly certain the code I need to fix goes in here.

```
apiRouter.route('/files')

        .post(function(req, res){

            var file = new File()

            //.attach = function(field, attachment, callback)
            file.attach('image', req.body, function(error) {
                // file is now uploaded and post.file is populated e.g.:
                // post.file.url
            })

        })

        .get(function(req, res){
           //get a list of all files goes here
        });
```

I fully expect I am missing something obvious, but MEAN stack programming is new to me, and I've scoured stackoverflow & the web at large looking for more examples or anything to hint at what I am missing. Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you should set up your location path of where you want the file to be saved on S3, currently in that example it's using the same path as the origin file (which could be `/var/tmp/y7sday...` or `C:/Users/SomeGuy/Pictures/..`) so we need to sort that out first.

In my code I'm using the same name as the file they gave, in production you might want to sort these by date and add a random uuid to them. [full example](https://github.com/eknowles/mongoose-crate-example/blob/master/app/models/file.js#L21)

```
FileSchema.plugin(crate, {
    storage: new S3({
        key: process.env.KEY,
        secret: process.env.SECRET,
        bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
        acl: 'public-read', // defaults to public-read
        region: 'eu-west-1', // defaults to us-standard
        path: function(attachment) { // where the file is stored in the bucket - defaults to this function
            return '/' + attachment.name
        }
    }),
    fields: {
        file: {}
    }
});
```

Next in your API endpoint you want to include any form information in the body and add those to the object, these will be in the `req.body` part.

The most important thing to note here is that I've set the attachment as `file`, this needs to match the field you have declared in your mongoose schema or it will die.

Next include `req.files.file` as the second argument. [full example](https://github.com/eknowles/mongoose-crate-example/blob/master/app/controllers/file.js#L30-L46)

```
exports.create = function (req, res) {
    var file = new File();
    file.title = req.body.title;
    file.description = req.body.description;
    file.attach('file', req.files.file, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            return res.send(error);
        } else {
            return res.send(file);
        }
    });
};
```

I've uploaded my workings to [GitHub](https://github.com/eknowles/mongoose-crate-example), so please do clone that and try it out.

All you need to do is **POST** to /file/

```
{
    "description": "My Description",
    "title": "My Title",
    "file": {
        "url": "https://mysecretbucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bb4bf9f69bf41ab478824d80a338beb6.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "name": "bb4bf9f69bf41ab478824d80a338beb6.png",
        "size": 8912
    },
    "_id": "553e8ed8282cc30000000001"
}
```

Make sure that you set the field in the form to be `file` like the image below

[image]

Comment: Here is the files schema https://github.com/eknowles/mongoose-crate-example/blob/master/app/models/file.js

and the api https://github.com/eknowles/mongoose-crate-example/blob/master/app/controllers/file.js#L30-L46

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much for the effort you put into answering this. This goes a long way towards helping me understand express routing in general. I owe you one. Stack says I have to wait 20hrs before rewarding the bounty, but rest assured it's yours!

Comment: No worries! Express is an awesome framework, loads of really great stuff out there!

Comment: Any chance you could  modify your example for Express 4? express.multipart is removed from the Express 4.x library so I can't use the built in parser like your example does. I've been using [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser), but maybe I will need to use [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty)

Comment: You can use https://github.com/expressjs/multer for Express4, it's very simple to setup